# Elastic search query for name / value pair columns pull

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query, aws-elasticsearch

We have one document in elastic search with multiple sections of name/value pair and we want to fetch value's only based on name column value.

```
"envelopeData": {
  "envelopeName": "Bills",
  "details": {
    "detail": [
      {
        "name": "UC_CORP",
        "value": "76483"
      },
      {
        "name": "UC_CYCLE",
        "value": "V"
      }
```

We are expecting only 76483 as result based on name equals to **UC_CORP**

Comment: Might be this link help you https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-aggregate-nested-key-value-pairs-only-if-they-match-a-filter/53076/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field **envelopeData.details.detail** is [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type then you can perform a match query for the desired name on the nested path and can use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) to get just the value.

Map the field **envelopeData.details.detail** as nested(if not nested):

```
PUT stackoverflow
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "envelopeData.details.detail": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then you can perform the following query to get value using **inner_hits**:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "_source": "false", 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "envelopeData.details.detail",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "envelopeData.details.detail.name.keyword": "UC_CORP"
        }
      }, 
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": "envelopeData.details.detail.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs:

```
{
  "_index": "stackoverflow",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "W5GUW2gB3GnGVyg-Sf4T",
  "_score": 0.6931472,
  "_source": {},
  "inner_hits": {
    "envelopeData.details.detail": {
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.6931472,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "stackoverflow",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "W5GUW2gB3GnGVyg-Sf4T",
            "_nested": {
              "field": "envelopeData.details.detail",
              "offset": 0
            },
            "_score": 0.6931472,
            "_source": {
              "value": "76483"  -> Outputs value only
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think my data is not nested type. Getting below error. "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason": "[nested] nested object under path [notificationJson.envelopeData.details.detail] is not of nested type"
          }

Comment: GET delivery/_search
{
  "_source": "false", 
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "notificationJson",
            
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"notificationJson.envelopeData.details.detail.name" : "UC_CORP"} }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
        "_source": "notificationJson.envelopeData.details.detail.value"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: In output I am getting all value fields but I want only the matched one  _source": {
                    "envelopeData": {
                      "details": {
                        "detail": [
                          {
                            "value": "e9556"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "A"